# SYNTAXERROR: Keyword can't be an expression - From blackjackcode

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
elif playercount > dealercount:
      **print("YOU WIN WITH" + playercount = "POINTS")** # <----- error#
      print("Dealer has: " + str(dealer) + "or" + str(dealercount) + "points")
      break
```

This is a segment of code from a blackjack game i have been making. I use the playercount as how many points the player has. It follows the normal rules of blackjack.
When i run the code it outputs an error 'SYNTAXERROR: Keyword can't be an expression'.

All of the code https://github.com/Alexios99/BLACKJACK/blob/master/BlackjackGame

Comment: Typo. `=` should be `+`. I prefer [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/): `print(f"YOU WIN WITH {playercount} POINTS")`

Comment: Use `... + playercount + "POINTS"` instead of `... + playercount = "POINTS"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on Johnny Mopp's comment:

You have an unessesary `**` in two places. Besides that, you cannot assign a variable while using it as an expression (unless you use assignment expressions). Perhaps you meant to put `+` instead of `=`:

```py
print("YOU WIN WITH" + playercount + "POINTS")
```

Also, you can use python [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) instead. Code:

```py
elif playercount > dealercount:
      print(f"YOU WIN WITH {playercount} POINTS") # <----- error#
      print(f"Dealer has: {str(dealer)} or {str(dealercount)} points")
      break
```